# Extract only the numbers from String

Tags: java, regex, string

I need a Regex that given the following Strings: "12.123.123/1234-11", "12.123123123411" or "1123123/1234-11". 
I could extract only the numbers(12123123123411);

```
Pattern padrao = Pattern.compile("\d+");
Matcher matcher = padrao.matcher("12.123.123/1234-11");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
//output:12,123,123,1234,11,
//I need: 121231234123411
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Pattern padrao = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A better way would be use [`String#replaceAll(regex, replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method to replace all characters except digits (As you see, the method takes a regex for replacing):

```
String str = "12.123.123/1234-11";
String digits = str.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

`\\D` matches non-digit characters. Equivalent to `[^0-9]`.
Note that, you need to escape the `\D` on Java regex engine.

---

If you have restriction for using `Matcher#group()` method, then you would have to build a `StringBuilder` instance, appending digits, everytime they are found:

```
String str = "12.123.123/1234-11";
StringBuilder digits = new StringBuilder();

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
    digits.append(matcher.group());
}

System.out.println(digits);
```

Comment: I really need to do this with the match.group() method. Is it impossible? Or very hard to do?

Comment: @CristianoPassos. It's possible, and probably not that hard. But the prefered way would be this one. I'll add a solution using `group()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply remove all the non-digit characters through replaceAll:

```
String out = string.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
```